# Is there another way to create a JavaScript associative Array without JSON?

Tags: javascript

I wonder if there is another way to have an associative array in JavaScript without having to use JSON.

Now I know this:

```
var json = '{ "color": [ "red", "blue" ], "name": "Ionut" }';
```

Is there another way to declare an associative array? Like in PHP for example.

Comment: You mean like `var foo = { "color": [ "red", "blue" ], "name": "Ionut" };`? Please note that objects !== associative arrays. JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays.

Comment: Why do you want to create Javascript Objects, which is basically associative array with string keys, without using javascript object notaion?

Comment: *"Like in PHP for example."* How would you do it in PHP? It's not really clear to me what you are asking for...

Comment: What you appear to be asking is "Is there a built-in way to create an associative array in JavaScript without using built-in the associative array syntax". The answer is yes, `Map` and `WeakMap`.

Comment: @Ben That answer is semantically correct, however it's likely entirely useless. :P

Comment: @FelixKling, what I mean is like when you have key and value in PHP, whitout objects.

Comment: You may be confused about something here... Javascript has **key-value maps**, a.k.a. objects, and **lists**, a.k.a. arrays. PHP *only* has arrays for both these purposes (associative key-value pairs and indexed lists). PHP *objects* are yet another thing PHP has, but it's mostly used for instantiating classes. Javascript doesn't have the latter. So, what do you want? Key-value pairs? Then you want Javascript objects.

Comment: I'd say the fact that PHP has a single data structure that acts as keyed collection *and* indexed collection is rather the exception. Languages usually have separate data structures for this: Objects and arrays in JavaScript, dicts and lists in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is a text-based data format and is only tangentially-related to JavaScript.

Associative array-like functionality is achieved in JavaScript via objects and their properties.

The limitation of this approach is that the keys must be strings (or symbols in ES2015).

So the syntax for an associative array in JavaScript is:

```
var a = { 
  'key1': 'value1', 
  'key2': 'value2', 
  /* ... */ 
};
```

The only other ways to achieve similar functionality in JavaScript are the more modern `Map` and `WeakMap` which extend the capability to permit objects as keys. `WeakMap` keys do not prevent garbage collection of the objects used as keys.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply omit the outer quotes:

```
var foo = { "color": [ "red", "blue" ], "name": "Ionut" };

// access
var color = foo['color'];

// modify
foo['name'] = 'Better name';

// add
foo['bar'] = 'baz';
```

Longer explanation: JSON is a serialization format. It describes how to turn JavaScript objects into Strings and back.

The standard evolved around normal JavaScript objects which allow to emulate associative arrays.

Comment: @deceze: JavaScript opjects have properties which can't be found in simple associative arrays. So you can emulate them but they aren't the save.

Comment: Well, you can "simulate" aspects of Javascript objects with associate arrays and vice versa. Speaking in terms of approaching functionality of one thing with another is weird. PHP and JS are different beasts and they both have their own idioms of how to do things. You need to learn it from that angle, not how to best "imitate" one using the other.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var json = {};
json[ "color" ] = [];
json[ "color" ].push( "red" );
json[ "color" ].push( "blue" );
// or json[ "color" ] = [ "red", "blue" ];
json[ "name" ] = "Ionut";
```